# Should I compress a Bitmap before POSTing it to a server?

Tags: android, post, bitmap, multipart

I have a question regarding best practices for this. If I am doing a multi part request to a server, should I compress the .jpg file (assuming the .jpg file is large) I would be POSTing to the API on the client (Android) side?

Or is this usually not a problem since .jpg handles lossy compression already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of compressing, you may want to resize it instead. Take a look at [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)).

Answer (score 1):

Jpg is already a compressed format Compressing a jpg file might even result in a larger file.

Comment: Right this is the hunch I had, I am sending a .jpg TypedFile to a server and it is taking 5 seconds for a response. Is this normal?

Comment: It depends on many factors such as available bandwidth, noting that you go as fast as the slowest link. How large is the file? How responsive is the server?

Comment: It's same on multiple wifi networks for multiple users. If it helps any here is the content length Content-Length: 435543 Do you think it could be an issue on the server side with how the API was implemented?

Comment: With 1Mb actual bandwidth, a 0.4 MB file transfers in roughly 4 seconds. Test your upload capability to that site using FTP or the like.